# pgr_dijkstra many-to-many invalid memory alloc request size

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, pgr-dijkstra

I am trying to find the shortest path 'from' many locations 'to' many locations.  Unfortunately there are many 'from' and 'to' locations which causes pg_dijkstra to fail.  For example, I have 97 'from' locations and 3829 'to' locations.  Is there a way to limit the number of candidate 'to' locations, since they are not all reachable.  Not sure if you can do it, but maybe limit the search area of each 'from' point to say 10 km, which in turn would limit the number of 'to' points.

Example below:

Yellow circle = example 'from' locations & Black circle = example 'to' location
[image: example screnario]

Below is my code:

```
-- ### Begin Dijkstra algorthm shortest path query ###
CREATE TABLE waterbody.vertices_lookup AS 
WITH all_pairs AS (
  -- all pairs of start and end geometries with IDs
  -- that get carried through so the routing results
  -- match with the pt IDs you know.
  SELECT f.id AS fid, f.geom as fgeom,
         t.id as tid, t.geom as tgeom
    FROM public.from_pts1 AS f,
         waterbody.to_pts AS t
), vertices AS (
  SELECT fid, tid,
       (SELECT id -- proximity search for closest from vertex
          FROM waterbody.water_streams_vertices_pgr
         ORDER BY the_geom <-> fgeom
         LIMIT 1) as fv,
       (SELECT id -- proximity search for closest to vertex
          FROM waterbody.water_streams_vertices_pgr
         ORDER BY the_geom <-> tgeom
         LIMIT 1) as tv
  FROM all_pairs
)
SELECT * FROM vertices;

-- ### Begin Dijkstra algorthm shortest path query ###
CREATE TABLE waterbody.pgr_routes AS 
WITH pgr_result AS (
  SELECT pgr_dijkstra(
    'SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM waterbody.water_streams',
    array_agg(fv), array_agg(tv), 
    directed := true
  ) FROM waterbody.vertices_lookup
)
-- join original from and to vertices to pgr dijkstra results
SELECT (pgr_dijkstra).*, a.fid, a.tid FROM pgr_result
JOIN waterbody.vertices_lookup a
ON (pgr_dijkstra).start_vid = a.fv
AND (pgr_dijkstra).end_vid = a.tv;

-- select total agg_cost value of routes for from and to locations
CREATE TEMP TABLE total_cost AS
SELECT * FROM waterbody.pgr_routes  
WHERE pgr_routes.edge = -1;

-- min distance value of agg_cost results for from and to locations
CREATE TEMP TABLE pgr_routes_min AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON (fid) fid, tid, agg_cost
FROM total_cost
ORDER BY fid, agg_cost;

-- Left join min distance results to wtrcrossing locations
CREATE TABLE waterbody.wtr_dwn AS
SELECT public.from_pts1.*,pgr_routes_min.*,waterbody.to_pts.wtrbdy_cr
FROM pgr_routes_min 
LEFT JOIN public.from_pts1
ON pgr_routes_min.fid = public.from_pts1.id 
LEFT JOIN waterbody.to_pts
ON pgr_routes_min.tid = waterbody.to_pts.id;
```

Comment: You could try running One to Many. i.e. from each of your 'from' points to the all of the  'to' points.
I have done this in the past by writing a function which iterates through 'from' points. Is this what you are looking to do?

Comment: @MJM - I'm happy to look into your objective; is this still the data https://github.com/matthewmeadows81/example-data you are using?

Comment: @TimothyDalton I have uploaded into github with today's date.  A brief summary is provided in uploaded zip.  Many thanks.

Comment: @MJM I'll continue on Github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason for the memory allocation error is not the amount of sources and destinations sent to pgrouting but a flaw in the syntax after the `pgr_dijkstra()` query, namely `FROM waterbody.vertices_lookup`.

To make things a little easier to follow, I am posting a solution using a loop which in every iteration makes a one-to-many computation (cc @Cushen). The results are aggregated ending up with the many-to-many result OP is asking for. The `vertices_lookup` table comes in handy as an auxiliary table to look up the nearest vertices. I have added inline comments for further explanation.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_shortest_routes()
    RETURNS TABLE (
        source_vertex bigint,
        destination_vertex bigint,
        source_id int,
        destination_id int,
        cost float,
        sequence int[],
        edges bigint[],
        nodes bigint[],
        geom geometry(LineString, 4326) 
    )
AS
$$
DECLARE
    _source int;
    _destinations int[];
    _start timestamptz := clock_timestamp();
    _stop timestamptz;
BEGIN 
    -- destinations are always the same
     _destinations := ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT tv FROM vertices_lookup);
    FOR _source IN -- we loop over every distinct source vertex
        SELECT DISTINCT(fv) FROM vertices_lookup
    LOOP
        -- one-to-many computation
        RETURN QUERY SELECT  
            _source::bigint AS source_vertex, -- the source vertex
            MIN(r.end_vid)::bigint AS destination_vertex, -- the destination vertex
            vl.fid::int AS source_id, -- from the vertices_lookup table
            vl.tid::int AS destination_id,
            SUM(r.cost) AS cost, -- we sum up the cost
            array_agg(r.path_seq) AS sequence, -- aggregated pgroutings response into arrays
            array_agg(r.edge) AS edges,
            array_agg(r.node) AS nodes,
            ST_Collect(ws.geom) AS geom
        FROM pgr_dijkstra(
            'SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM water_streams',
            _source, 
            _destinations, 
            directed := true
        ) AS r
        -- here we join with water streams to get the geometry
        JOIN water_streams AS ws
        ON r.edge = ws.id
        -- and we join with the vertices lookup to retrieve the ids
        JOIN vertices_lookup AS vl
        ON _source = vl.fv
        AND r.end_vid = vl.tv 
        GROUP BY end_vid, vl.fid, vl.tid
        -- we order our many by cost
        ORDER BY cost
        -- and just keep the shortest/cheapest route
        LIMIT 1;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Which can simply be called with:

```
CREATE TABLE shortest_routes 
AS SELECT 
    source_vertex,
    destination_vertex,
    source_id,
    destination_id,
    cost,
    sequence,
    edges,
    nodes,
    ST_CollectionExtract(geom) AS geom
FROM find_shortest_routes();

ALTER TABLE shortest_routes ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE shortest_routes
ALTER COLUMN geom type geometry(MultiLineString, 4326)
USING ST_SetSRID(geom, 4326);
```